# Setting width of lines in tabular

Tags: tables, width

Is it possible to increase the linewidth of tables like it's possible to set the linewidth in PSTricks?

Maybe you could show me how to do it on this example:

```
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
    \hline
    5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: If you also need the space between columns, use `\tabcolsep` macro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 \setlength\arrayrulewidth{1cm}
```

before the table will make the lines thicker

Comment: Simple and solves my problem. THX!

Answer (score 2):

with package `booktabs` you can use an optional argument.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\setlength\aboverulesep{0pt}
\setlength\belowrulesep{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}\toprule[3pt]
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\     \midrule[2pt]
    5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\     \bottomrule[1pt]
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

the setting

```
\setlength\aboverulesep{0pt}
\setlength\belowrulesep{0pt}
```

is only for compatibilty to standard LaTeX. It is better *not* to use these two lines.